# Find the volume - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

I was asked to find the volume of the shape that is the intersection of the two cylinders $x^2+y^2 \leq 1$ and $x^2+z^2 \leq 1$

My solution is false, I would like to know why it is not good.

by reducing 1 equations from the other, you can get $y^2-z^2 \leq 1$, and so $y^2 \leq 1+z^2$

so the bounds for $y$ are: $-\sqrt{1+z^2} \leq y \leq \sqrt{1+z^2}$

since $x^2+z^2 \leq 1$ we can get that $z^2 \leq 1-x^2$ and as such $-\sqrt{1-x^2} \leq z \leq \sqrt{1-x^2}$

and $-1 \leq x \leq 1$ is our "free" variable that has no restrictions.

using wolfram alpha, i calculate this tripe integral which should theoretically give me the volume of the shape requested:

$$\int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \int_{-\sqrt{1+z^2}}^{\sqrt{1+z^2}}1dydzdx$$ and the result wolfram alpha gave me is $6.99215$.

After googling a bit, I stumble upon this page http://www.math.tamu.edu/~Tom.Kiffe/calc3/newcylinder/2cylinder.html that says the answer is $\frac{16}{3}$.

1) I do not understand how they calculated the volume on that page.

2) I don't understand where I went wrong.

Would appreciate clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two $\iint$ represent your region of integration here you are using 
$\displaystyle \int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} $ this is a very well known region, it's circular region.

In method $(2)$ When you intersect two cylinders, you get a square region as in the link.

[image]

The also note that the height function of this intersection of cylinders are different on different regions, as one cylinder's height is taller than other on some region. On region $(a)$ cylinder $(2)$ is taller than cylinder $(1)$ therefore cylinder $(1)$ acts are bounds for floor and ceiling.

[image]

In method $(1)$ you take a circular region, and use another cylinder for bounds.
[image]

Comment: thanks to your help I managed to solve it correctly :)

Comment: @OriaGruber you are welcome :)

Comment: What I changed was, basically the boundary for $y$ was incorrect. I changed it to $-\sqrt{1-x^2} \leq y \leq \sqrt{1-x^2}$, same as $z$, and $x$ still goes between $-1$ and $1$ and the answer is correct. Now I wonder, the volume of what shape did i calculate before? when I was wrong

Comment: @OriaGruber I find this little un-intuitive, I prefer method $(2)$ ... let me add a little bit on method $(2)$.

Comment: @OriaGruber find the volume of the region in above figure which is triangular and height is curved cylinder and then multiply it by $4$